# С чего вы начинали

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! С чего вы начинали изучение Java, меня интересуют в первую очередь, какие проекты вы реализовывали в начале обучения ?

Comment: fizz  buzz

Comment: Hello world! же

Answer (score 3, accepted):

начал с курсовой по предмету, можно было выбирать любую тему: я выбрал сделать простенький чат для локальной сети на UDP (у нас уже был свой придуманный протокол и пару готовых клиентов на других языках). условие курсовой был апплет на java, почти все получилось :)

недостатки:
1) надо было конфигурировать permissions, - я тогда не разобрался как это делать (небыло времени)
2) неверно отображались цвета - почему-то у половины панелей цвет background не применялся =/

преимущества:
у апплета изначально был метод main, - в котором создавался фрейм с этим же апплетом. как standalone проложение он работал на ура, результат всех устраивал :) удобство языка и слегка навязанное ООП повлияло на результат: сейчас пишу на java

все програмки а-ля "hello world" писать небыло возможности из-за отсутствия времени, програмы такой сложности просто просматривались по ходу прочтения книжки.

p.s. это был не первый язык который я учил, до этого были basic - школа, pascal - школа + универ, c++ - универ, VB 6.0 - self education + универ, asm - универ

Answer (score 2):

Начинал с консольного приложения, которое работало с командной строки и занималось перекодировкой текстовых файлов из разных кодировок: CP866, KOI8, Win1251, Mac и проч. - давно это было

Второе приложение был научный калькулятор со спецфункциями, парсером и проч. - был реализован в виде апплета

А потом пошло поехало...

**Update**
Да, начиналось все 1995-м году

Comment: романтика то какая... вспомнить свою первую программку на яве, как это было.. =)

Answer (score 1):

Первый опыт коммерческой разработки на Java: для одной судоходной компании написал Swing программулину, которая читала входящие с радиосвязи телетайпограммы определенного вида из директории и пересылала нужному адресату по внутренней почте. И программу-близнеца, которая делала ровно обратное (мониторинг почтового ящика и генерация телетайпограммы в выходную директорию).

А апплетиками баловался еще в 14 лет на JDK 1.4. Тогда у меня не было даже интернета, а только купленная на южном отдыхе свежевышедшая книга [Секреты программирования для Internet на Java](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/136540/) (JDK прилагался на диске).

Answer (score 0):

Нейронная сеть с обратным распространением ошибки.
P.S. не очень правильный вариант, так как много расчетов с плавающей запятой.

Answer (score 0):

После десятка простых лабораторных работ курсовая работа планировщик заданий (сильно упрощенная версия MS Project). Данные хранились с использованием СУБД hSql, доступ к данным осуществлялся через Hibernate, а пользовательский интерфейс реализован на Swing. В итоге собственно до алгоритма планирования дело так и не дошло..:) Но был реализован интерфейс введения основных исходных данных, и этого было достатчно для сдачи курсача. Следует заметить что в данный момент программирую в основном на C#, благо для него есть порт Hibernate :), а с того времени появились уже и собственные ORM.